# How can I disable account settings?

Tags: distributions, users

I am using Drupal 6 with the OpenAtrium distribution, and I'd like to completely remove the account settings menu. In other words, I don't want users (or, even better, certain users) from access account settings. I know that it can be done by hiding the menu via CSS, but I am looking for some kind of module that can make it easier.

EDIT:

Ok what I did was creating and activating a new module called disablepermissions:

```
function disablepermissions_menu_alter(&$items){
     $items['user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
     $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = FALSE;
     $items['user/%user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

This actually works as intended but if I try to set some kind of permissions I only get a blank page with a 500 Internal Server Error, why? The following code does not work...

```
function disablepermissions_perm() {
    return array('visualizza utenti');
}

function disablepermissions_menu_alter(&$items){
     if (access_user('visualizza utenti') {
     $items['user']['access callback'] = TRUE;
     $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = TRUE;
     $items['user/%user']['access callback'] = TRUE;
     }
     else {
     $items['user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
     $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = FALSE;
     $items['user/%user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
     }
}
```

Comment: To which account settings are you referring? What is the URL of that setting page?

Comment: /user/n/edit where n is the id of the user ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6). Something like this should work:

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['user/%user_category/edit']['access callback'] = 'yourmodule_user_custom_access_function';
}

function yourmodule_user_custom_access_function($u){
  return user_access('administer users');
}
```

This way, only users with "administer users" permissions will be able to edit user informations.

Comment: I am not really into Drupal that much. Let's say I add this code to an existing module who will call the subroutine? I'd like to understand how things work before changing code.

Comment: Ok what I did was creating a custom module with the code you provided. I activated the module, cleared cache but nothing has changed :(

Comment: Uhm... Do I have to install additional modules in order to access hook_menu_alter()? Because I see it is part of core.php under /development/hook folder but I don't have that folder on my system at all.